# Is it possible to turn off the jQuery UI?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Is it possible to turn off the jQuery ui on a few moments? I need this because a `.toggle('slide')` with `jQuery UI` it's not the same as without it. This effect have a difference. But I need that UI was on after this effect has complete?

Comment: What's the difference with the effects?

Comment: Do you want to show the target state of the UI animation?

Comment: I have `.toggle('slide')` in my script, without a jQuery UI. But when I used jQuery UI this effect absolutely other.

Comment: check http://jqueryui.com/toggle/ and somewhere on the fiddle: `<div id="test">TOGGLE SLIDE</div>` `$('#test').toggle('slide');` `div { border: 1px solid #ccc; }` animation is not the same.

Comment: @RocketHazmat with ui it's like left edge hidding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few options:

1. Remove the `jquery.ui.effect.js` which provides for all effects in jquery UI.
2. Turn off animations in jquery programmatically by settings `$.fx.off = true;`
3. If you need the effects but don't like how they look, simply pass more options to `.toggle` to make it look like what you want. The documentation for both methods ([ui](http://api.jqueryui.com/toggle/) and [plain jquery](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)) seems to indicate they both default to 'swing' easing and '400ms' duration, so the animation should be very similar already.

Comment: yeah, seems the third is good!